# Pandas: add rows to each group until condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a time series dataframe with the following structure:

```
| ID | second | speaker1 | speaker2 | company | ... |
|----|--------|----------|----------|---------|-----|
|  A |    1   |     1    |     1    |  name1  |     |
|  A |    2   |     1    |     1    |  name1  |     |
|  A |    3   |     1    |     1    |  name1  |     |
|  B |    1   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  B |    2   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  B |    3   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  B |    4   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  C |    1   |     1    |     1    |  name3  |     |
|  C |    2   |     1    |     1    |  name3  |     |
```

`*note that speaker1 and speaker2 can be either 0 or 1, I set all to one for clarity here`

> I would like to add rows to each group until every group has the same number of rows. (where num of rows = ID with the most rows)

> For every new row, I would like to populate the speaker1 and speaker2 columns with 0s while keeping the values in the other columns the same for that ID.

So the output should be:

```
| ID | second | speaker1 | speaker2 | company | ... |
|:--:|:------:|:--------:|:--------:|:-------:|:---:|
|  A |    1   |     1    |     1    |  name1  |     |
|  A |    2   |     1    |     1    |  name1  |     |
|  A |    3   |     1    |     1    |  name1  |     |
|  A |    4   |     0    |     0    |  name1  |     |
|  B |    1   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  B |    2   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  B |    3   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  B |    4   |     1    |     1    |  name2  |     |
|  C |    1   |     1    |     1    |  name3  |     |
|  C |    2   |     1    |     1    |  name3  |     |
|  C |    3   |     0    |     0    |  name3  |     |
|  C |    4   |     0    |     0    |  name3  |     |
```

So far I have tried a groupby and apply, but found it to be extremely slow as I have many rows and columns in this dataframe.

```
def add_rows_sec(w):
    'input: dataframe for grouped by ID, output: dataframe with added rows until max call length'
    
    while w['second'].max() < clean_data['second'].max(): # if duration is less than max duration in full data set
        last_row = w.iloc[-1]
        last_row['second'] += 1
        last_row['speaker1'] = 0
        last_row['speaker2'] = 0
        return w.append(last_row)
    return w

df.groupby('ID').apply(add_rows_sec).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Is there a way of doing this with numpy? Something like

```
condition = w['second'].max() < df['second'].max()
choice = pd.Series([w.ID, w.second + 1, 0, 0, w.company...])
df = np.select(condition, choice, default = np.nan)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What does this mean? `I want to add rows for each unique ID until every ID has the number of rows equal to the ID with the most rows.`

Comment: Essentially just adding rows to each group until every group has the same number of rows. (where num of rows = ID with the most rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach with pandas

1. construct a Dataframe that is Cartesian product of `ID` and `second`
2. outer join it back to original data frame
3. fill missing values based on your spec

No `groupby()` no loops.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C"],"second":["1","2","3","1","2","3","4","1","2"],"speaker1":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],"speaker2":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],"company":["name1","name1","name1","name2","name2","name2","name2","name3","name3"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":df["ID"].unique()}).assign(foo=1).merge(\
    pd.DataFrame({"second":df["second"].unique()}).assign(foo=1)).drop("foo", 1)\
    .merge(df, on=["ID","second"], how="outer")

df2["company"] = df2["company"].fillna(method="ffill")
df2.fillna(0)
```

**output**

```
    ID  second  speaker1    speaker2    company
0   A   1   1   1   name1
1   A   2   1   1   name1
2   A   3   1   1   name1
3   A   4   0   0   name1
4   B   1   1   1   name2
5   B   2   1   1   name2
6   B   3   1   1   name2
7   B   4   1   1   name2
8   C   1   1   1   name3
9   C   2   1   1   name3
10  C   3   0   0   name3
11  C   4   0   0   name3
```